# Changing the sky background color

Tags: drake

I want to change the background colour (default blue sky) for rendering. How would I go about doing this?

I'm using `MakeRenderEngineGl` for rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the `default_clear_color` in the `RenderEngineGlParams` struct. See the [C++](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/structdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_render_engine_gl_params.html#a24b99c9946848c937df22ef2b8745d65) documentation or the [python](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html#pydrake.geometry.RenderEngineGlParams) docs here.

The term "clear color" is a term of art from OpenGl. It's what the buffer is "cleared" to before drawing. So, it is the "background" color.